# Registering an app permission in SharePoint

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-app-registration

I am needing to connect from Azure (Azure data factory) to SharePoint sites
When I then create a linked service, I get the following error

```
Failed to get metadata of odata service, please check if service url and 
credential is correct and your application has permission to the resource.
```

So, here is what I am doing - detailed:

- I registered an app in Azure Active Directory and then went to Grant permission to that app ("add-in" in SharePoint language, if I get it right) with the SharePoint.

So, in the following, I am not understanding:
[image]

1.) What to put for domain ? and for redirect.
Is it something like "www.myCompanyDomain.com" and http://www.myCompanyDomain.com ?
or is it something to be taken from Azure Registered app configuration ?

2. ) In the XML pasted, the "Scope" - Do I specify it literally as it is shown ? (Actually http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection) or is it to be replaced with my company's sharepoint Farm URL ?

Would appreciate any help ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In domain you can use `localhost` and `https://localhost` in redirect url like following pic
[image]

In the XML, just specify it literally as it is shown and don't replace with your company's sharepoint Farm URL. You can refer to the document for the scope
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint
[image]

Comment: So, after I authorize an app this way, is it possible to check if it it still authorized later (tomorrow, the day/month after )?  So, if I go to https://[your_site_url]/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx, and lookup the registered app by ID, should I see back the xml snippet I entered before ?